# PL/SQL - define precision and scale for number parameter of stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have a stored procedure that inserts the values from parameters into a table. One of the parameters should allow numbers with a precision and a scale to allow calling the procedure the following way: `EXECUTE operation(10, 10, 2.5)`. The problem is there seems to be no way to define such things for parameters in PL/SQL. It works when I set the type of the parameter to `VARCHAR2` and call `to_number` afterwards but this would alter the way of calling the procedure because of the apostrophes.

So is there a way to pass a number in a format such as `NUMBER(8,2)` to a procedure?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can't specify scale, precision, or size for parameter datatypes.

Comment: @acroyear, why you can't? I did not find an explanation of this.

Comment: @MaxMakhrov Not sure why, but it is part of the language definition. If you need to restrict the scale, precision, or size, you could do so inside the procedure.

Comment: Furthermore Oracle / PLS/SQL seems to be extremely hostile in case of this error. I get completely irrelevant error messages (various `PLS-00103`) when parameter declaration has scale or precision. This is completely mindboggling as this error is so easy to make and errors are so weird.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the problem.

What's wrong with

```
create procedure operation (par_1 in number,
                            par_2 in number,
                            par_3 in number
                           )
as ...
```

It accepts `(10, 10, 2.5)`. So ...?

Demonstration:

```
SQL> create table test (a number, b number, c number);

Table created.

SQL> create or replace procedure operation
  2    (par_1 in number, par_2 in number, par_3 in number)
  3  as
  4  begin
  5    insert into test (a, b, c) values (par_1, par_2, par_3);
  6  end;
  7  /

Procedure created.

SQL> exec operation (10, 10, 2.5);

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * from test;

         A          B          C
---------- ---------- ----------
        10         10        2,5

SQL>
```